# Can Asynchronous Generators be called using a pass through / helper function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, async-await, yield-return

### What I can do

I figured out that the asynchronous generator pattern is fairly new to JavaScript and only available in Node.js as of version 10. So after I did all that, I can now use the following function to yield multiple similar elements in a web page using Selenium, which uses async/await for many of its functions:

```
formElements = async function*(containerCss, childCss, defaultCount) {
    let countCSS = containerCss + " " + childCss;

    let numElements = await countCss(countCSS) || defaultCount;

    for (let cIndex = 1; cIndex <= numElements; cIndex++) {
        let elementCss = containerCss + ":nth-child(" + cIndex + ") " + childCss;

        yield await elmCSS(elementCss);
    }
}
```

This function works fine as an asynchronous generator using this call:

```
for await (const button of formElements("button-container-css", "button-css", 6))
{
    await clickOn(button);

    //other async stuff...
}
```

### What I can't figure out

But what I want to do is take those specific parameters out of the main function and have a helper function (`formButtons()`) provide them instead, which I think should look like this (?):

```
formButtons = async function*() {
    yield await formElements("button-container-css", "button-css", 6);
}
```

so my main function can be a LITTLE cleaner:

```
for await (const button of formButtons())
{
    await clickOn(button);
    //other async stuff...
}
```

But it literally skips everything once it hits the `yield` in `formButtons()`, returning null and causing errors. I think the error must either be in my `formButtons()` function or else it's some unfortunate artifact of not using the stable release of Node, but I'm hopeful it's something I can fix

Is there an error or a workaround for this?

Comment: I'm not experienced with generators but is this a case where you need `yield*`?

Comment: @Pointy took me a moment to figure out what you meant and try it out, but yes - add that as an answer (maybe with a link :-P), and I'll accept it :-)

Comment: Answer added. Hopefully I got the same solution you ended up with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that I've used generators only a few times in toy applications, the situation you've got is basically a delegation from one generator to another one. Since what you want to do is "pass through" control to the sub-generator completely, you can use `yield*` instead of `yield`.  It basically means, "yield everything you can get from this generator". So:

```
formButtons = async function*() {
    yield* await formElements("button-container-css", "button-css", 6);
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's such a tiny change, eh? Thanks!!